# Tomcat Realm get access to existing servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I want to implement custom realm which can invoke authorization method form servlet class. That servlet is deployed to server with existing application.

I guess that i can send http request from that realm or is there a better way to do this communication? Use servlet with rmi? Get servlet by JNDI lookup?

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe that'll help http://sureshkk.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/custom-realm-in-tomcat/

Comment: Thank you for replay. It is not exactly what i want. I want to use authentication method from my deployed webapp. (Realm should connect to that method throw some interface).